# How can I diagnose or solve the error "rule "package.paths" unknown" when trying to build Boost libraries 1.69.0 with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: boost

When attempting to build Boost 1.69.0 from *a fresh, clean, checkout*, on Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2017, I encounter the following confounding error message:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
C:/90cf73ea/tools/boost_install/.\boost-install-dirs.jam:15: in boost-install-dirs.includedir
ERROR: rule "package.paths" unknown in module "boost-install-dirs".
C:/90cf73ea/libs/headers/build/../../../tools/boost_install\boost-install.jam:721: in boost-install.install-cmake-config
libs\headers\build\Jamfile:87: in modules.load
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:375: in load-jamfile
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:64: in load
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:89: in load-used-projects
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:75: in load
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:145: in project.find
C:/90cf73ea/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:618: in load
C:\90cf73ea\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
C:\90cf73ea\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
C:\90cf73ea\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I am executing the build commands from the VS2017 command prompt. I am able to execute "bootstrap.bat" without any issues. Running "b2.exe toolset=msvc-14.1" (regardless of any further arguments) results in the above error message. How can I go about diagnosing and/or resolving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remotely understand why this would be the case, but I solved this issue by **updating *git* from version 2.18.0 to version 2.20.1.**

I got this advice on the boost build mailing list:

> This error indicates that the the build submodule is not up-to-date.
>   - Steven Watanbe

I speculate that something in git version 2.18.0 struggled with the boost build submodule. Moral of the story seems to be, check if your git version needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, in my case, I had cloned the Boost repo (currently at 1.70.0). Tried to build and got this error. I then did a "git status" and found a bunch of libraries that were untracked (presumably from the 1.70.0 branch). Removing all untracked directories allowed me to build.

Hope that helps someone!